# Initialize std::vector in a struct

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a struct with 2 `std::vector`s as given below. I want to initialize the vector with 2048 elements having initial value 0.0.

```
struct PixelMaps
{
    vector<double> pixelMapX;
    vector<double> pixelMapY;
};
```

I tried the following code. This creates the vector of 2 elements only. How can I initialize the structure with 2048 elements in a single statement with initialization list?

```
PixelMaps test{ {2048,0.0}, {2048, 0.0} };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor using `std::initializer_list`, so you can't use brace-init-list - it will always end up in that constructor. You need more explicit initialization:

```
PixelMaps test{ std::vector(2048,0.0), std::vector(2048, 0.0) };
```

Or (pre C++17)

```
PixelMaps test{ std::vector<double>(2048,0.0), std::vector<double>(2048, 0.0) };
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your C++ taste, in C++20 you could write

```
#include <vector>

struct PixelMaps
{
    std::vector<double> pixelMapX;
    std::vector<double> pixelMapY;
};

int main() 
{ 
    
    PixelMaps test {
        .pixelMapX {std::vector(2048,0.0)},
        .pixelMapY {std::vector(2048,0.0)}
    };
}
```

This is known as [designated initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).